# an interface may only extend a class or another interface / mapped types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, interface

I use `typescript 2.1` along with `JSX` and I try to use `Partial` mapped type for extend interface of react component with optional properties from interface with required properties.

this is interface with required properties:

```
interface ActionsCreators {
  A: string;
  B: string;
};
```

this is interface which I want to extend:

```
interface Props extends React.Props<any> {
  C: string;
};
```

this is mapped type:

```
type ActionsCreatorsPartial = Partial<ActionsCreators>;
```

which give this result:

```
type ActionsCreatorsPartial = {
  A?: string;
  B?: string;
}
```

this is what I try to do:

```
interface Props extends React.Props<any>, ActionsCreatorsPartial {
   C: string;
};
```

but I see compilation error: "an interface may only extend a class or another interface" How can I connect interface `Props` with `ActionsCreatorsPartial` type?

Comment: Workaround: `type Props = React.Props<any> & ActionsCreatorsPartial & { C: string; };`

Comment: I think your comment deserves to be the answer

Answer (score 2):

The error message is correct, interfaces can only extend other interfaces or the interface of a class, and classes can likewise only implement interfaces or take the interface from another class.

There is an approved [suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11207) to let classes implement type aliases, I guess it would be in scope to also let interfaces extend type aliases if that is implemented.

Unfortunately, as of today, I don't think that there is any way to incorporate a mapped type into a interface.

Comment: on the theoretical side I like your answer, but with a practical side comment from David Sherret is what I needed :) I will upvote your answer  anyway.

Comment: @RajabShakiro Thank you, but you only asked for how to make an interface, I had no idea that a intersection type would fit your need. If you describe more in detail what you are/were trying to accomplish, maybe you could have even better answers here